# Spark: What's the difference between spark.sql and sqlCtx.sql

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark 2.1 using pyspark, if you want to query a table (e.g. from HDP) you can run both

```
df = sqlCtx.sql(''' select * from table ''')
```

and

```
df = spark.sql(''' select * from table ''')
```

Why would you do one over the other? What is the difference between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqlCtx` is the default `SQLContext` created on startup. `spark` is the default `SparkSession` created on startup. According to the documentation for [`SQLContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext) `SparkSession` is the replacement for `SQLContext`:

> As of Spark 2.0, this is replaced by SparkSession. However, we are keeping the class here for backward compatibility.